# How to debug this site in IE9?

Tags: web-development, internet-explorer

Just finished this site: http://brodr-haukaas.no And to my horror it doesn't work properly in IE.

Something is breaking my slider script, and I don't have much experience in debugging JS code using any of the browser debuggers. I need to use the IE9 debugging tool, but how would I do the break points? Where should I start? It would be great if someone could point me to some good resources with examples to go from.

*Not sure if this belongs under Wordpress, programming or here. But I feel it's a fairly general web debug question.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE has it's own developer tools built in. Just press F12.

Microsoft have their own documentation: [How to use F12 Developer Tools to Debug your Webpages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507%28VS.85%29.aspx)